# Unable to trigger SonarLint Analysis on whole Project

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarlint

I have installed the latest sonarLint plugins with Intellij 2016.1.2.
Analyze on the fly works fine. However, I can't find in the IntelliJ "Analyze" tab any "Analyze with SonarLint". In the SonarLint window>issues tab, I can only see scope "current file" or "opened files". I don't see any Project scope.
So my question is how to trigger the analysis on my whole project ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Since [SonarLint v2.8](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLI-28), it's possible to analyze all files in the project.**

Open the `SonarLint Tool Window`, go to the `Project files` tab, and click in the "play" button.
There is also an action to which you can assign a shortcut.

More information here: https://www.sonarlint.org/intellij/howto.html

Comment: Well from the screenshot on the http://www.sonarlint.org/intellij/resources/images/intellij.png  we can see a "Project" scope so it's a bit confusing. Anyway thank you for this tools. Any plan for implementation of Project scope ? :p

Comment: Indeed, the "Project" scope was confusing (it was showing all known issues in the project based on per-file analysis) and for that reason it was removed in the latest version. We are still internally discussing that feature - currently there are no plans to move forward with it. You can track the corresponding ticket here: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLI-28

Comment: 90% of the time I work with existing code. My use case is not to click through every file to find sonar issues. It would be much more easy to have an overview directly in SonarLint, instead of having to switch from the sonar server to my ide manually. Sorry, checking my current file is the least of my worries.

Answer (score 13):

The easiest two ways to do project analyze:

1. Choose **Analyze | Analyze with SonarLint**
2. Press **Ctrl + Shift + S**

Comment: That's correct. You must just take care to select the project - instead of just one source file - in the `Project` view. Otherwise the Report is made only for that source file.

Comment: or right click project and click on sonarlint then analyze!

Answer (score 2):

As @Duarte - SonarSource Team suggests Sonar-Lint has a different purpose. It is intended to use to analyze for code changes in current file(s). i.e. it cannot perform analysis which needs to compare 2 files. (ex: finding duplicates, coverage etc.)

For your purpose that best way to achieve is running [SonarQube with preview mode](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE51/Getting+Issues+Report+in+Preview+Mode).

**Update**:

As per [this](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/how-to-configure-sonarqube-preview-mode-to-comment-less-verbose/7336), the preview mode has been deprocated in v 6.6 and will be dropped in future.

Comment: please  update the attached link it is  no  more  available  (404)

Comment: @Ikbel thank you for pointing, please see my update added

Answer (score 1):

they stated many times that their intent is to support only new issue being introduced running an on-fly analysis on files being changed.
If you wanna run a full analysis you should use the SonarQubeCommunity plugin or visit your remote Sonar Server. 
If you wanna gather only coverage information within your IDE, use the Jacoco plugin.
However there is an open feature request to browse those issues directly in the SonarLint plugin: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLE-54

Yes, that screenshot is confusing, but that feature was previously available.

Answer (score 1):

Since version [2.8](https://jira.sonarsource.com/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=11131&version=13656) analysis of all files in the project is possible.